# Find the date for next 15th using php

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to find the date when it's next 15th.
I came across this [Get the date of the next occurrence of the 18th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774645/get-the-date-of-the-next-occurrence-of-the-18th) but this shows the today date if its' 18th..I want to see August 18th 20111.

Is there any way to get the next 15th?

regards

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: hi, i just tried the one in the above link..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                                   // dynamic typing FTW
$next15th = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n') + (date('j') >= 15), 15);

echo date('Y-m-d', $next15th);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried a few dates (past and future), it showed the right result. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the link you provided above, I would assume you change the following:

```
$nextDay = 18;
```

I'd change that to:

```
$nextDay = 15;
```

Comment: but as i said, this shows the current month if it's today.for example, today is 15th, and if you run the code, i would expect aug 15th , but this shows july 15th.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(date('d') >= 15)
    $date = date('Y-m', strtotime('+1 month')).-'.$nextDay
else
    $date = date('Y-m').'-'.$nextDay;
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the code in the above link just changed > to >= and the 18 to 15